# getResource not working

Tags: java, imageicon, getresource

im trying to load a image from src folder

the file: /src/Imagens/user_login.png

but the getResource doesnt work :( i tryed to solve, but look the images

First Try:

[image]

Second Try, removing the getClass for the Class real name:

[image]

Third Try, lets add a .class after the name "Oh, i think i solved":

[image]

DAMM!!! what can i do? i can use the IMageIcon for Images in C:/ or other location, but from the src, i cant

Comment: Try `"/imagens/user_login.png"`

Comment: HOLY... i LOVE YOU!!

solved, but just a inverted / and lost / made all this :(!!

Comment: The file separator is always '/' and not '\\' because the argument to `getResource` is a URL, not a file path.  URLs always use '/' to separate path components, on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You try to acces non static method `getClass()` from static context(method `main()`). You can use from static context:

```
inicializador_tela_login.class.getResource(...)
```

or create instance of class and use `getClass()` method:

```
new inicializador_tela_login().getClass().getResource(...)
```